# Ubuntu 16.10 software center keep showing os updates

Tags: updates, 16.10

Software Center from time to time shows in Software center that i have updates named OS Updates, i can't see that kind of behavior in Ubuntu 16.04, is this normal in Ubuntu 16.10 or this is bug?

Comment: Have you ever installed those updates or not ?

Comment: i'm confused because software center in 16.10 doesn't work well, when i click on OS Updates and i see progress bar how updating, but when process of updating is finished OS Updates icon keep staying in Updates tab like update isn't updated...

Comment: Well sometimes this also happens in Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I recommend you to install updates using Software Updater.

Comment: and why not for example through Terminal?

Comment: You can use terminal. I just thought that maybe you like GUI method as you were earlier trying to install updates through Ubuntu Software Centre!